# Ports to be opened for remote capturing

Tags: wireshark, tshark, winpcap, pyshark

I am trying to capture remote tcp packets using tshark/pyshark. I can see the packets in wireshark if the firewall in the remote machine is turned off. It doesn't work with the firewall on. I have the tcp ports 2002 and 1448 opened in the remote machine firewall.

I have run the rpcapd service with the command `rpcapd -n`

If any of you have done remote capturing behind the firewall, your help will be much appreciated

Comment: In which mode are you running rpcapd? active or passive?

Comment: I think this article will be useful for you:https://www.cisco.com/assets/sol/sb/WAP321_Emulators/WAP321_Emulator_v1-0-0-3/help/Admin30.html

Comment: @mik1904 passive mode. tried active mode as well, but don't know if i did it correctly. ```rpcapd -n -a <ip>,2002```

Comment: Okok, It definitely looks like a firewall problem. Cannot help much without knowing them which is not really safe to post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `netstat` i checked the ports listening and found that there is a random port between 30000-39999 listening everytime my pyshark program sniffs.

I was having windows server 2008 which prevented me from opening a range of ports.

So the solution to my problem was to allow the rpcapd.exe program in the firewall.